# Spark ThriftServer caching

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

'Fresh' queries that have never been run by that user/session seem to result in some caching on first run. Specifically two Spark jobs are produced, the first job caches the data (seemingly on disk) and then second actually executes the sql. Moreover, the cache seems to expire after some time.

Is there a way to optimize this process so that the caching can occur when the tables are registered in the Hive metastore? Can the caching persist?

Our workflow:

```
//register the parquet files as hive tables
spark.catalog.createExternalTable("schema.table","s3a://some/table/", "parquet")

//query tables via jdbc, first execution takes minutes for caching
select column from schema.table where partition = value

//query tables via jdbc, second execution even with different values, is much faster
select column from schema.table where partition = another_value
```